# PostgreSQL schema migration?

Tags: postgresql, schema-migration

I've local PostgreSQL database with tables, constraints, relations etc.

How can I migrate it to a production server?

Comment: why not pg_dump and restore?..

Comment: http://liquibase.org/

Comment: @VaoTsun I get following error while using pg_dump:
`pg_dump: server version: 9.6.5; pg_dump version: 9.5.10`

`pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `liquibase` or `flyway` is good approach, but    I'am at the end of developing my app. These tools must be used from the start of developing an app (put each sql script into file and store them )

Comment: You can introduce Liquibase for an existing database: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html I don't use Flyway but I'm sure it can do something similar.

Comment: @DauletNurgali you try to use old pg_dump with new server - while you  should do the opposite. try `locate bin/pg_dump` to find pg_dump for 9.6 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html) manual page you can try with **pg_dump** and **psql**, you can also check other **flags** for data, schema or table specific tasks. I personally sometime do this kind of job using [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-premium) or [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) client.

To dump a database called **mydb** into a SQL-script file:

```
$ pg_dump mydb > db.sql
```

To reload such a script into a (freshly created) database named **newdb**:

```
$ psql -d newdb -f db.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`flyway`](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how). It does exactly this. Dump your schema into an sql file and migrate using `flyway`.